# Intel Wi-fi 6 AX200 adapter not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, 20.04, iwlwifi

The wifi settings page complained that no wifi adapter can be found. here's some relevant information

```
lshw -C network

 *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fc600000-fc603fff

lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

i also tried to follow the instructions on this page
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release and also downloaded the firmware file from here https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi and copied it over to `/lib/firmware`

i also tried to boot in insecure mode but doesnt work either.

FYI, my kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic and I'm running only ubuntu 20.04 on my PC (not dual-booting)

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok I've edited the output

Comment: It should work. Let's see what happens. Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: And please fix the question with another command, I made a typo `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with AX200 (rev1a). I have a dual-boot (Windows 10, Ubuntu) and I turned both Fast Boot and Secure Boot in BIOS off, but the Wi-Fi still didn't work. After running the command:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

I saw an error:

```
failed with error -110
```

And I found in [a conversation](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205299), that I need turn off Fast Boot in Windows too.

It helped me. It was a lot of time.

Comment: Same for me. Needed to disable windows fast boot. Then Wifi was back. Problem occurred after new Bios was installed. Machine: Intel Nuc 9 Extreme Laptop Kit. Remark:
Additionally the Keyboard backlight vanished. This needed a new windows software (gamer keyboard), then backlight worked properly again after setting once with new software. All started with windows system update installing new Bios…

Comment: thanks a lot, you save my life. Turn out it related to Windows, not the Linux or ubuntu itself, thanks for your solution

Comment: Thank you for this. You saved me alot of time.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, disabling fast startup under windows definitely worked for me:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
This problem was very annoying because wifi sometimes worked and sometimes not. I couldn't figure out why it only stopped working sometimes, mostly after booting windows. This "random" thing also made it quite difficult to search for answers on the web. Thanks a million for solving the mystery! :)

Answer (score 3):

After disabling the "Fast Startup" the issue got resolved for me.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1315022/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing and tried a lot of different fixes. What i *think* fixed it was updating my kernel.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
chmod a+x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
sudo ./ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
```

I restarted the PC and it didnt initially work so i turned the machine off. When i turned it back on in the morning, the wifi was back!

Im now running the following kernel and the wifi seems to be reliable.

```
#~ uname -r
5.8.0-050800-generic
```

The error i was getting was something about failing to load the module `-110`. Now i get the following:

```
#~ sudo dmesg | grep iwl                                                                                                                        
[    4.603886] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.616449] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.616872] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.616974] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.617037] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.617393] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.617447] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.617503] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.617559] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.620011] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    4.620022] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.620027] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.620484] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 cc-a0-48.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.620500] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    4.636288] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    4.658356] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.658499] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.826168] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: base HW address: a8:7e:ea:6c:93:f5
[    5.128612] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0 wlp82s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.117844] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.285828] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

Some of the other things i tried were making sure i didnt have the hardware switch on and removing/reloading the kernel module:

```
sudo rmmod iwlmvm
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlmvm
```

I tried installing the driver direct from intel - https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html
But that didnt seem to work.

I tried installing the backports as well but again, that didnt seem to work for me.

```
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

In my /lib/firmware, i have a lot of `iwlwifi` ucode files now....

```
#~ ls *iwl
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode   iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode    iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode   iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode              iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode    iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode    iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode   iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode              iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode    iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode    iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode              iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode    iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode              iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode   iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode              iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode   iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode   iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode  iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode  iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode   iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode  iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode   iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode   iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode  iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode  iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode   iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode  iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode  iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode   iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode    iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode   iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode  iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode   iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode  iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode    iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode  iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode   iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
```

So if updating the kernel driver dosent work, try those other things.

I found that when i updated my kernel driver, i had to switch my nvidia graphics to the open source driver as well as the kernel update seemed to break the graphics so that i couldnt connect external monitors. I did this through the UI by selecting  Additional Drivers -> Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-450 (open source)

(Previously it was on 440-proprietary)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day! I did an automatic update on my laptop and after a restart my WiFi (internal Intel WiFi card) was gone. I tried reinstalling the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and tried some other suggestions. But only the kernel update did the trick. My kernel before was 5.13.22 and now it's 5.15.4.

Comment: I'm facing a relevant issue (much of which may be attributed to GitHub). Last sudo apt update/upgrade included a 3rd kernel (2nd kernel update) removed 100% networking function. BUT: Because I've no internet function by NIC/Wifi I can't do as suggested. I then tried downloading that kernel you said in Windows 11, (3x) Android 10 on 3 devices, 2 Nokia N900's, 1 Nokia N9, 1 BSD os, a live USB Debian system but all resulted in 0 ability 4 direct download as well as wget for those which can. The download appears to need to be done from within the system w/ no internet access (making it impossible

Comment: It's strange that GitHub removed that 1 button to download the file before your eyes. If it were still there I could do so in any of the systems & copy the file to the 2 Ubuntu OS's with 0 IP function (after kernel update to both).

Answer (score 2):

You can update the intel backports and wifi driver using this. It will update the kernel needed for the wifi driver. It worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Answer (score 1):

If I ran `inxi -Fxz` it would show no driver for my Wi-Fi.

I had a new computer and had only booted into windows once. Used my Linux for about three days and then had switched and came back to Linux to find no Wi-Fi. It was as @IncSaint mentioned. Basically, Windows fast boot doesn't shut down all the way and saves some stuff to memory, interfering with Linux setup for Wi-Fi. The answer was to turn off fast boot.

> on Windows 10 it should be in “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System Settings”. Select “Choose what the power buttons do” to access the System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”.

My access was slightly different - choose what power buttons do was in power options.

[About dual-boot with Windows and "fast-boot" enabled](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so if you just installed Linux from a running Windows installation, you may have had Fast Boot enabled. Try to fully power cycle the machine. The network card may be getting passive power, thus keeping itself in a disabled state, which Linux does not seem to be able to enable it from automatically. This fixed Wi-Fi on my system after many attempts at solving the issue.

Comment: Can confirm. After reading tons of threads on this issue, updating kernel, drivers etc nothing would work. It turns out if you install Ubuntu replacing Windows you no longer have an access to Fast Boot disable option but wifi adapter is still somehow held by already uninstalled Windows. Full power cycle (including removing AC cable) fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

My wifi adapter on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS sometimes also not working. Just tried turn-off (restart not working), unplug source cable from power supply(only turn-off-on also not working), turn-on without electricity, plug in source cable to power supply and turn-on. It is weird but wifi is back. I was motivated to do this, because I read and also experienced that after turn-off PC at night and turn-on at morning wifi was working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions such as disabling fast boot, disabling secure boot, updating kernel and etc...

What finally worked was upgrading my Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions such as disabling fast boot, disabling secure boot, updating kernel and etc...

What finally worked was to swap the card to another PCIEx1 slot.

May it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this:

```bash
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up # check ifconfig to get your wifi device name!
sudo nmcli radio wifi on
```

The secret sauce here seems to have been the `nmcli` command.

Answer (score -1):

If any of y'all are dual-booting with Windows, you may need to add a registry key to use UTC time in Windows. Running Zorin OS 16.1, also ran into the same issue in PopOS, both of which are Ubuntu-based forks. Seems to be some sort of clock synchronization issue.

The below link has instructions.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_time#UTC_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1222669)