# Cannot get an Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a) to work with Mate 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, intel

In this case a Feb Smart card because I found it listed in an Ubuntu compatible list.

`sudo lshw`   returns

`*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 1a
                serial: 78:2b:46:d9:a5:35
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:16 memory:ef000000-ef003fff`


`sudo lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A3`

Yields

`00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM [8086:15e3]
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM [1028:07a1]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi`

`sudo lshw -class network`   produces

`*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 78:2b:46:d9:a5:35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ef000000-ef003fff`

I have:

- downloaded and installed the latest version of the firmware from Intel
- tried the Atheros drivers through Ath10k.  They're all now blacklisted.

Only the iwlwifi driver got the Wifi and Bluetooth icons to appear on the toolbar.

When I try to connect to my Wifi netowrk, I get the password screen but the connection always fails. During the initial connection

`sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status`

returns

`H/W path           Device      Class          Description
=========================================================
/0/100/1d/0        wlp1s0      network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6   network        Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                     CONNECTION         
enp0s31f6       ethernet  connected                 Wired connection 1 
wlp1s0          wifi      connecting (configuring)  neonjohn 1         
p2p-dev-wlp1s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected              --                 
lo              loopback  unmanaged`

When the authentication screen is presented,

`H/W path           Device      Class          Description
=========================================================
/0/100/1d/0        wlp1s0      network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6   network        Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                             CONNECTION         
enp0s31f6       ethernet  connected                         Wired connection 1 
wlp1s0          wifi      connecting (need authentication)  neonjohn 1         
p2p-dev-wlp1s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected                      --                 
lo              loopback  unmanaged`

## After entering the password

`H/W path           Device      Class          Description`

/0/100/1d/0        wlp1s0      network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6   network        Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                     CONNECTION
enp0s31f6       ethernet  connected                 Wired connection 1
wlp1s0          wifi      connecting (configuring)  neonjohn 1
p2p-dev-wlp1s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected              --
lo              loopback  unmanaged

The connection always fails.  "neonjohn" is the SSID of my network.  The antennae are about 4 ft away from the router.  I've reset the router several times.

With the bluetooth, the menu appears but it does nothing when I select "devices" even though I have a BlueTooth speaker sitting next to the antennae.

This is the third day I've been working on this problem and I'm at my wit's end.  Please Help

### John

More information

If I reboot and uninstall the driver and then reinstall it, the WiFi connects immediately.

`sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi`   Producing

`remove (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
rmmod mac80211
rmmod libarc4
rmmod cfg80211`

then
 `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`  producing

`nsmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko`

The WiFi connects immediately.

Anyone have any thoughts about this?
Thanks
John

UPDATE 02/11/2021

Taking the above action disabled my wired ethernet port.  I had to remove the driver to get my wired connection back.

I have now purchased and returned 3 PCIe cards recommended as being compatible.  A WiFi dongle that worked on 16.04 also fails.  It looks like Canonical screwed the pooch on networking on this release.

Two questions:

Does anyone know of a PCIe combo wifi/bluetooth card KNOWN to work with 20.04 LTS?

Has the networking been fixed in 21.04?  I want to stay with LTS releases but I also want networking.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show power management on when it won't connect?

Comment: @user1908895 Take a look this thread, one of the answer there might work for you: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263279/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-adapter-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04`

Answer (score 0):

I never solved this problem.  I bought and returned 3 other linux-compatible PCIi cards.  None would come up.  Neither would an WiFi dongle.  Looks like wireless networking is really screwed up on this release.

Anyone know whether 21.04 solved the network problem?

Thanks for all the help

John