# How to copy the kernel available in live usb to the system ubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, kernel, updates

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed in my system, with the `5.15.0-56-generic` and `5.15.0-53-generic` kernels available. I am having issues with my wifi drivers using these kernels and want to downgrade to `5.15.0-46-generic` available on the live usb I created where the wifi driver works without issues.

Simply copy paste by click doesn't work, but even through terminal I'm not sure which all files need to be copied and to which all locations. Also do any config files or such need to be updated so the kernel shows up in the grub menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving driver issues by kernel downgrade might not be a good idea and will run into a dead end.

Anyway, the kernel 5.15.0-46-generic can be directly installed with

`apt install linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic`

you will need to pin the packet and remove other kernels. I hope you know what you are doing. It's dangerous. do a full backup first.

Regarding the `Wi-Fi 6 AX200` driver:
did you check

[intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-adapter-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263279/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-adapter-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04)

[getting-intel-ax200-wi-fi-to-work-on-ubuntu-20-04](https://www.miklix.com/linux/getting-intel-ax200-wi-fi-to-work-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

?

Comment: Hey thanks, ya i had figured out the apt part but booting from this old kernel did not solve my wifi issue and in fact the system would simply hang. Luckily I didn't remove the latest drivers. Atleast recovery mode works with those. Will check out the posts you tagged, thanks.